# How can i validate my users social profile links

Tags: twitter

I have a problem with social profile link.

How can i force users to add valid and existing social profile links.

Each user can add their Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn Profile Link but i see, they add for twitter '@ProfileName' instead of http://www.twitter.com/pagename and some users added 'Facebook Name'(John Martin) instead of 'http://www.facebook.com/johnmartin' and same for linked in.

I try to find a best solution but i can't.

Can anyone give me a good solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the social site's API to validate user's profile link. But you will need each user to be logged in to their social site account before they can authorize your app for at least basic access to their profile.

The profile link you get from the API should be valid, but may look a little cryptic; for example the link may not contain a user's first and/or lastname like: Facebook.com/Johnmartin but instead, it might look like Facebook.com/16gu65uw.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/social-links

It may solve your problem.